# How to position inner div (vertical progress bar) at the bottom of outer div?

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, and am attempting to create a vertical progress bar component - illustrating a tank level.

This is what I have so far:

```css
tank-bar {
    .progress-outer {
        height: 96%;
        margin: 10px 2%;
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
        color: dark;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .progress-inner {
        min-height: 15;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: map-get($colors, secondary);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not quite there yet and looks like this in the browser:

[image: Incorrect progress bar]

I would like to show the green part (percentage full) from the bottom and not from the top of the outer div.

Any help would be much appreciated, I am still pretty horrible at CSS and Sass, but trying to get better through tutorials.

Edit*

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="progress-outer">
    <div class="progress-inner" [style.height]="Level + '%'">
        {{Level}}%
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML would be nice to!

Comment: Sorry! Added it now

Comment: The rendered html?

Comment: Works for me with the CSS from before the edit...

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your CSS to make the outer container relative, and the inner container absolutely positioned and anchored to the bottom within it, like so:

```
.progress-outer {
    height: 96%;
    margin: 10px 2%;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
    color: dark;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.progress-inner {
    min-height: 15;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: map-get($colors, secondary);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

it should work.

Note the changes are:

```
position: relative;
```

in `.progress-outer`

and

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

in `.progress-inner`

Comment: That results in the outer div to shrink and no longer encompass the smaller div (at least thats how it appears).

It also sits in the bottom left

Comment: You could set `left: 0; right: 0` for the inner container to get it to extend to the full width of the outer container.

Answer (score 0):

Positioning the child as absolute of its relative parent will allow you to specify where it sticks. This comes with a few catches, including needing to specify its width now that it has been taken out of normal document flow (where it would normally measure its block width).

```
// Spacing between the edges of outer/inner, since
// padding values will be ignored with position: absolute.    
$offest: 2px;
$fullOffset: $offset * 2;

tank-bar {

    .progress-outer{ 
        position: relative;
        // etc...
    }
    .progress-inner{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: $offset;
        left: $offset;
        width: calc(100% - #{$fullOffset});

        // Include padding/margins in the width calculations of this child element.
        box-sizing: border-box;

        // etc...
    }

}
```

I added a little offset variable to give a bit of space that I see in your sample. You can remove/modify that if it's not actually what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the flexbox layout. Set the `display` rule of the parent to `flex` and the `align-items` rule to `flex-end`. Also make sure to set the `flex` rule on the child to `0 1 100%`.

Here is an example

```js
let prog = document.querySelector('.progress-inner')

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      prog.style.height = i + 1 + '%'
      prog.textContent = i + 1 + '%'
    }, 100 * i)
  }(i))
}
```

```css
.progress-outer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 96%;
  margin: 10px 2%;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
  color: dark;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.progress-inner {
  min-height: 15;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: lightgreen;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic-framework/2.0.0-beta.2/ionic.ios.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="progress-outer">
    <div class="progress-inner">
        0%
    </div>
</div>
```